# Spring security - resource j_spring_security_check not avaiable

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am trying to build a Spring based web application and I would like to start with configuring a simple authentication system based on username & password tuples stored in a database table.

It is my understanding that this can be easily achieved using Spring security, but I cannot get it to work.

The following is my **web.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/Servlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Follows the **servlet-context.xml** file. The bob and sam users are there for testing purposes. After I get this right I will switch to a JDBC based user service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <sec:http use-expressions="true">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
        <sec:form-login
            login-page="/home.html"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-failure-url="/login-error.html"
            default-target-url="/welcome.html" />
        <sec:logout logout-success-url="/home.html" />
    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager>
        <sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:password-encoder hash="md5"/>
            <sec:user-service>
                <sec:user name="bob" password="12b141f35d58b8b3a46eea65e6ac179e" authorities="ROLE_SUPERVISOR, ROLE_USER" />
                <sec:user name="sam" password="d1a5e26d0558c455d386085fad77d427" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </sec:user-service>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <context:component-scan base-package="cz.dusanrychnovsky.whattoreadnext" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

This is my Home controller.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController 
{   
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home.html")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login-error.html")
    public String loginError(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

And this is my thymeleaf based view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring3-3.dtd">
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

    <head>
        <title>Contacts</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Welcome to the site!</h1>

            <p th:if="${loginError}">Wrong user or password</p> 
            <form th:action="@{/j_spring_security_check}" method="post"> 
                <label for="j_username">Email address</label>: 
                <input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username" /> <br /> 
                <label for="j_password">Password</label>: 
                <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" /> <br /> 
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" /> 
             </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I deploy the WAR file to my local Tomcat installation and visit the `http://localhost:8080/test/home.html` URL, the home page opens fine. When I fill in the form, though, which gets submitted to `http://localhost:8080/test/j_spring_security_check`, I get a `404 - The requested resource () is not available.` error.

What am I doing wrong? Please bear with me as I'm  a newcomer to both Spring MVC/Security and Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to [configure Spring Security filter in `web.xml`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-web-xml)
2. You cannot configure Spring Security in `servlet-context.xml`, because `servlet-context.xml` belongs to specific `DispatcherServlet`, but Spring Security filter works before request reaches any servlet.

   You need to [create a root application context using `ContextLoaderListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-create) and put Spring Security configuration there.

   Actually, as long as you don't need separate `servlet-context.xml` and `applicationContext.xml`, I'd suggest you to move everything from `servlet-context.xml` to `applicationContext.xml` and leave `servlet-context.xml` effectively empty (that is, leave its `<beans>` element empty).